# Applying rotation before FeatureToRaster_conversion?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, raster, arcpy

I am converting polygon shapefiles to rasters. With arcpy I am using the function `FeatureToRaster_conversion`.

```
gp.FeatureToRaster_conversion(InFeatures, InField, OutRaster, InCellSize)
```

This function gives control of the cell size but nothing concerning the rotation.

I would like the output raster with a given orientation other than North. Say for example having the picture at 45 degrees.

Any ideas how I can achieve this? With or without using FeatureToRaster_conversion.

Comment: I should have mentioned it is not the entire raster that I want to rotate but the actual cells (or pixel) that compose it. As it is the function convert from polygon to cells oriented at 0 degrees. I need this conversion from polygon to cells oriented at 45 degrees.
If operating manually on Arcmap it will be similar to rotate (firstly) the map than export it as raster.

Comment: Doesn't Rotate(Data Management) does this?

Comment: If using 'Rotate' the entire picture will rotated around a given point (lower left corner by default). This will move spatially the features I have on the raster. This transformation is not wanted.
I need to sample on my raster already oriented at 45deg the shapefile. Probably nobody looks at pixel level about raster but for my case it is important.

Comment: Making some progress. I start to believe arcpy might not support what I need. Gdal library does support rasterising on cells of different orientation. The SetGeoTransform function has arguments for rotation. An interesting thread on the subject here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220749/rasterizing-a-gdal-layer

Comment: If you decide to come back to this question I recommend that you use the comments that you added onto it to revise it.

Comment: Thanks Polygeo. This is how I worked around the problem. 1/ Quit your job. 2/ Forget it all about Arcmap and other proprietary software. 3/ Make your own company.

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate your raster using a Rotate Raster Tool. Find it in Data Management, Projections and Transformations, Raster Toolset. It works under all license levels.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can go through [Rotate (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000007s000000). It rotates input raster.

Answer (score 0):

Don't really have a great idea as far as something in the API, but as far as a strategy you can find something that allows you to set the lat/lon values and simply calculate how to change them to satisfy a 45 degree rotation. If you switch those values you would get 180 degrees so find less than half of those values I would imagine.